# Django Error (Attribute): 'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_related'

Tags: python, django, forms, attributeerror

I am trying to make a description to every user, in my new project. But i get an error when i try to makemigrations. I do not know how to fix it.
I have tried different things but nothing worked, my coding is maybe very bad, but i am also new to python and django.

**The Error:**

```
C:\Users\bruger\Dropbox\min-login-web\web_login>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 143, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 322, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 378, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 87, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 85, in state_forwards
    list(self.managers),
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 377, in __init__
    if field.is_relation and hasattr(field.related_model, '_meta'):
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

**My Models file:**

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

class Desc(models.Model):
    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 250, required=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Desc'
```

I Hope somebody can help me, because this is really getting on my nerves.

Comment: maybe you should use `models.CharField` instead of `forms.CharField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed *forms* and *models*. A model does *not* specify a (HTML) form, it specifies how the database should store data, so you need to use a `models.CharField`:

```
class Desc(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Such `CharField` has no `widget` assigned to it, this is something you should handle at the *form* level.

You probably will need to make migrations, since up to this point, there was no `description` field in your `Desc` model.

I agree to some extent that it is confusing that the forms have frequently a field with the *same* name (well those typically are the default form fields for the model field with the same name). The idea is however that model fields specify the columns in a database, whereas form fields specify text boxes, check boxes, etc. in a (HTML) form.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot :D :D