# Django (TypeError): __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

Tags: python, django

I have the problem that, when i run my website it comes with two Type Errors. I do not know what it is i need to edit, but i know it is in the models.py file.

**Error 1:**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001D025692400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\bruger\Dropbox\min-login-web\web_login\users\models.py", line 25, in <module>
    class Desc(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\bruger\Dropbox\min-login-web\web_login\users\models.py", line 26, in Desc
    description = models.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 250, required=False)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1037, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'
```

**Error 2:**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000239D4B82400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\bruger\Dropbox\min-login-web\web_login\users\models.py", line 25, in <module>
    class Desc(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\bruger\Dropbox\min-login-web\web_login\users\models.py", line 26, in Desc
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 250, required=False)
  File "C:\Users\bruger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1037, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'
```

Here is my models.py, which the errors is in.

**Models.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

class Desc(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 250, required=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Desc'
```

I hope somebody can help, because im not that good at programming python, because i started this week. :D

Comment: You asked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734945/django-error-attribute-charfield-object-has-no-attribute-is-related and in response you got the idea of remove the widget attribute from model! right. Then why are you still using that

Comment: @a_k_v some people never learn...

Answer (score 2):

change

```
description = models.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 250, required=False)
```

to

```
description = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
```

`widget = forms.Textarea, required=False` is used in Form like:

```
from django import forms

class Desc(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 250, required=False)
```